# How do I know my unanswered questions will be revealed [to me] when I die?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, death

Many times as a Jew I think in the back of my head that certain question’s answers I greatly ponder will be revealed to me when I die.

I’ll give an example. A few distant relatives of mine were assumed to have perished in the Holocaust. But that is just because of the small information we had. It’s not necessarily true. And even if they did, we don’t know how and where etc.

What are sources in Judaism confirming or not this topic?

Comment: Welcome aboard, and thanks for the thoughtful question!

Comment: There is a (famous?) legend where two people (Rabbis?) make a pact that the first one who passes away will appear to the other in a dream to answer questions that the other had. As the legend goes, after the first one dies, he appears to the other in a dream and says that he has no idea how to give an answer, because in the next world there are no questions. Unfortunately, I have no idea what the source for this is, otherwise it would be an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: In a less direct manner, there is a Mishnah in Avos D'Rabbi Nosson (unsure of the exact location, I can try to find it over the weekennd. I think it may also have a parallel in the Gemara, but I'm not sure where) where a Chassid overhears two departed souls discussing what the upcoming weather pattern for the next years crops will be. While not a story that shows that 'all will be revealed' after death, it does show that after death, spirits can know things beyond the natural realm.

Comment: Story’s in brachot 18b @Salmononius2

Comment: @Shmuel Yup, that entire Amud has several similar stories from that theme. The parallel in Avos D'Rabbi Nosson is 3:8.

Answer (score -5):

A source may be in [Midrash Rabbah Bereishis 53, 14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.53.14?vhe=Daat_Bereshit_Rabbah&lang=bi):

> אמר רבי בנימין, הכל בחזקת סומין, עד שהקדוש ברוך הוא מאיר את עיניהם, מן הכא ויפקח אלוהים את עיניה, ותלך ותמלא החמת. [ויש אומרים כך: אמר רבי בנימין, **הכל בחזקת סומין, עד שיבוא הקדוש ברוך הוא ויפקח את עיניהם לעתיד לבא]**
>
> Says Rabbi Binyamin, Everyone is presumed blind until Hashem will come and open their eyes [in the future].

The point of this Midrash is that things we don't understand in this physical world are "intentionally hidden from our sight" by Hashem (presumably to enable the free choice between good and bad), but **in afterdeath Hashem just opens our [spiritual] eyes and things become evident by themselves**.

<sub>NB: The source of the addition in brackets is brought from [the site Kadouri.net](http://www.kaduri.net/?CategoryID=497&ArticleID=1860), it is not found [yet] in existing digitized editions of Midrash Rabbah and is questionable. Thanks to Ploni & Alex.</sub>

Comment: The version you linked to (as well as [this print](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=130)) does not contain the last part ("ויש אומרים..."), which is the basis for your answer.

Comment: In fact I checked 7 prints on Hebrew Books and none of them have this version.

Comment: @Ploni Check out the critical edition [here](https://ia800207.us.archive.org/3/items/bereschitrabba02albe/bereschitrabba02albe.pdf) p.573, especially the footnote. The entire passage might be suspect.

Comment: @Alex How did you find that?! Shkoyach!

Comment: Even the edition linked by @Alex doesn't have the part in brackets. *Where did you get this **bracketed** passage from?*

Comment: Even ignoring the fact that the quoted piece may not exist (per @Ploni), where do we see that your quote is referring to after death (per the OP's question)? My default assumption would be that 'future' would be referring to Messianic times, not to a persons' soul after death.

Comment: @Ploni A Bar Ilan search with the words "ויפקח את עיניהם לעתיד לבא" produced zero results.

Comment: I flagged this answer as low quality since as far as we can tell, this passage does not exist in the source it is quoted from.

Comment: Instead of criticizing my answer, would you direct your effort to write a better one? Maybe R' Kadouri had a different version of MR?

Comment: I'm not coming to criticize your answer. I originally thought it was good, until I found out that this doesn't exist. Also, I can't write my own answer, because I don't have one.

Comment: Btw, looking at the website you brought it from, it doesn't seem to be quoting Midrash Rabbah, but rather, what some people say for a certain segulah.

Comment: The first part "אמר ר' בנימין" does appear in many Midrashim, it is sufficient to the question by itself.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, nonetheless -Anti

Comment: Looking at the source from the Kaduri website, that gives even less support to your answer. It's using that line for a 'Segulah' to find something that you just lost. In theory, that means that 5 minutes after you say that, Hashem is going to enlighten your eyes and you'll find your missing car keys. How in the world can that be referring to a symbolic metaphor for after death a soul will know everything?